# Заменить строку не трогая окончания и добавить дополнительную строку

Tags: javascript, jquery, регулярные-выражения

В этом коде:

```
var a = "текста, текстов, текстами";
a.replace(/текст/g,"итог (подитог)");
```

Выходит такой ответ:

```
итог (подитог)а, итог (подитог)ов, итог (подитог)ами
```

Ответ должен быть таким:

```
итога (подитог), итогов (подитог), итогами (подитог)
```

Как такое реализовать?

Comment: `a.replace(/текст([а-яё]*)/g,'итог$1 (подитог)')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var a = "текста, текстов, текстами";
a.replace(/текст([а-я]+)/g,"итог$1 (подитог)");
```